# Setting property of a subtype class using reference abstract type

Tags: c#, oop

So I have abstract class

```
public abstract class Client
{
    public abstract void Send();
    public abstract void Get();
}
```

And now there are 2 classes that inherit from Client

```
public class ClientV2 : Client 
{
    public string Value1 {get;set;}

    //implement Send and Get method()
}
```

```
public class ClientV3 : Client 
{
    public string Value2 {get;set;}
    public string Value3 {get;set;}

    //implement Send and Get method()
}
```

For simplicity, Program class is general GUI class. Now when someone will click on checkbox a new object will be instantiated but also new controls will show, for example text box for Value 2. What I need to do is set a Value2 when someone will type something but since I am using abstract type I can't access that value, what do you think will be the best solution here?

```
public class Program
{
    private Client client; 
  
    public void Client2CheckboxChecked()
    {
        client = new Client2();
    }

    public void Client2CheckboxChecked()
    {
        client = new Client3();
    }

    public void Value2Changed(string newValue)
    {
        //Here I would need to set Value2 propertyu of a ClientV3 using client 
    }
  
    public void SendData()
    {
        client.Send();
    }
}
```

I can of course create a different type for client 2 and client 3 that is rather than

```
private Client client;
```

I would have

```
private ClientV3 clientV2; 
private ClientV3 clientV3;
```

But in a future there could also be a possibility for clientV4 and I want to minimize the amount of changes I would need to change in my Program class.

Comment: Hello Karol and welcome to SO. This is not much of a question since this can be very opinionated. Although I would simply suggest to add the prop on the abstract class and simply update it when required.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Since this is a UI thing and you have certain controls working on a concrete client and not the abstract one i would go on creating the equivalent of a user control in your UI Framework. That control then is specific to a certain client and can know and handle a concrete client. Then new client means new user control and the part handling the abstract part of your client can be kept unchanged.

Comment: why isn't the change handler (or the specific part of it) on the class implementation? Therefore, orientated to the object, rather than the generic process.

Answer (score 1):

you may create an abstract method `SetValue` that all the different clients must implement and where the actual logic is in. Then in your `Program.Value2Changed` just call that method:

```
public void Value2Changed(string newValue)
{
   client.SetValue(newValue); // may be ClientV2 or ClientV3 or whatever
}


class Client
{
    public abstract void SetValue(string newValue);
}
class ClientV2 : Client
{
    public override void SetValue(string newValue) => this.Value2 = newValue;
}
class ClientV3 : Client
{
    public override void SetValue(string newValue) => this.Value3 = newValue;
}
```

This delegates the task of setting the values from your `Program` to the `Client`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the parents cannot know what is in the inherited classes you can solve this problem with **Downcasting**

```
  public void Value2Changed(string newValue)
  {
      (ClientV3)client.Value2 = newValue;
  }
```